# Return pk of form after submission

Tags: django

I need to return the PK of a form after it is submitted so I can use it in a second form. Everything I find online about returning the PK is for a http redirect not storing it in a variable and working with it in the view

view

```
def createPostView(request):

currentUser = request.user
postForm = PostForm()
if request.method == 'POST':
    postForm = PostForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if postForm.is_valid():
        PostFormID = postForm.save(commit=False)
        PostFormID.author = request.user
        PostFormID.save()
        return #need to get pk from this form

    for f in request.FILES.getlist('images'):          
        test = PostImagesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if test.is_valid():
            instance = test.save(commit=False)
            instance.post = #need to use pk here
            instance.images = f
            instance.save()   
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/")
           
return render(request, 'blog/post_form.html', {'postForm': postForm, 'PostImagesForm':PostImagesForm})
```

Comment: Could you elaborate what you mean by primary key of the form? The form itself is not stored in the database but the model instance is. After executing postForm.save() you can get the pk which, by default, is the id of the instance. So you can get it with PostFormID.id. But in your case, you have specified commit=False, so you won't be able to get the id that way as it hasn't been added to the database. After you return you are no longer inside the view so your perception of how you would obtain/use the pk is wrong. Please rephrase your question with a better explanation of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `save()` method of the form returns the instance that just created/updated. So, you will have the PK value of the distance by doing as below,

```
instance = PostFormID.save()
my_pk_value = instance.pk
```